# Assign variable to array element where variable and array can be modified independently in ocaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml, variable-assignment

Here is the problem I can't get around, I'm working in ocaml to copy the elements of an array to a new array. I want to be able to modify these arrays independently from each other, but no matter what I try, a change to one array is reflected in the other array as well.
Here is a simplified example:

```
type sampleType = { a : int; b : int array };;
let x = {a = 5; b = [|1, 2, 3|] };;
let y = x.b;;
Array.set y 1 6;;
```

After running these commands I want:

```
y - : int array = [|1; 6; 3|]
x - : sampleType = {a = 5; b = [|1; 2; 3|]}
```

Instead `x` is being changed along with `y`, and

```
x - : sampleType = {a = 5; b = [|1; 6; 3|]}
```

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you format your code as code, by indenting it four spaces, or wrapping it in backticks `\`like this\``, your posts will be much more beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see from your experiments, this code:

```
let y = x.b
```

makes `y` refer to the very same array as `x.b`. It doesn't create an independent array. To create an independent array, you need to copy:

```
let y = Array.copy x.b
```

Answer (score 0):

I was specifically using 3d arrays, realized I had to apply `Array.copy` at the lowest level of the 3d array, rather than at the top level.

```
let arr = Array.init 3 (fun _ -> Array.init 3 (fun _ -> (Array.init 3 (fun _ -> {faces = [|0;1;2;3;4|]}))));;
let drr = Array.init 3 (fun i -> Array.init 3 (fun j -> Array.copy arr.(i).(j)));;
```

This gave me the result I needed.